# number some patterns in the string using R

Tags: r

I have a strings and it has some patterns like this

```
my_string = "`d@k`0.55`0.55`0.55`0.55`0.55`0.55`0.55`0.55`0.55`n$l`0.4`0.1`0.25`0.28`0.18`0.3`0.17`0.2`0.03`!lk`0.04`0.04`0.04`0.04`0.04`0.04`0.04`0.04`0.04`vnabgjd`0.02`0.02`0.02`0.02`0.02`0.02`0.02`0.02`0.02`pogk(`1.01`0.71`0.86`0.89`0.79`0.91`0.78`0.81`0.64`r!#^#@niw`0.0014`0.0020`9.9999`9.9999`0.0020`0.0022`0.0032`9.9999`0.0000`
```

As you can see there is patterns [`nonnumber] then [`number.num~] repeated.
So I want to identify how many [`number.num~] are between [`nonnumber].

I tried to use regex

```
index <- gregexpr("`(\\w{2,20})`\\d\\.\\d(.*?)`\\D",cle)
regmatches(cle,index)
```

but using this code, the [`\D] is overlapped. so just It can't number how many the pattern are. 
So if you know any method about it, please leave some reply

Comment: I just want to how many 0.827 like this pattern are between character which is nonnumber

Comment: Yes that is just what I want

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit`. We split at the backtick and count the position `diff`erence `which` of the values coerced to `"numeric"` yield `NA`. Note, that we need to exclude the first element after `strsplit` and add an `NA` at the end in the numerics. Resulting in a vector named with the non-numerical element using `setNames` (not very good names actually, but it's demonstrating what's going on).

```
s <- el(strsplit(my_string, "\\`"))[-1]
s.num <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(s))
setNames(diff(which(is.na(c(s.num, NA)))) - 1,
         s[is.na(s.num)])
# d@k       n$l       !lk   vnabgjd     pogk( r!#^#@niw 
#   9         9         9         9         9         9
```